# What is a "for(;;)" loop used for?

Tags: java, syntax, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Infinite loop application - for(;;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923128/infinite-loop-application-for)

I am a Java developer, and I saw this in one of the classes:

```
for(;;){
something goes here
}
```

What does this loop mean?
When would we have to use it?

Thanks

Comment: It is an infinite loop. http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/ControlFlow/infinite.html

Comment: @WilliamShatner If you have an answer, why not post it as answer (instead of a comment)?

Comment: @delnan I didn't realize that I posted as a comment and when I did, a few people had already provided the OP with the same answer. Glad I was able to provide OP with a source to read about it though :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923128/infinite-loop-application

Comment: I like to write `for (;/*ever*/;)` to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an infinite loop, an equivalent of this could be

`while(true)` which is definitely used a lot more than an infinite for loop.

But they both mean the same thing in this situation.

Answer (score 5):

It's an infinite loop. Similar to `while(true) { ... }` or `do { ... } while(true);`. A reason you might use this is if in the `something goes here` part, you have a `break;` with a complex condition.

For simple break conditions, it's easier to just put them in the loop statement.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as

```
while(true)
```

However it's less used and in general should be avoided.

Comment: Well, although you can argue it's a matter of preference (and it is) it is an idiom that makes little sense. The preferred idiom is one that would make obvious to the reader what it is doing. Much like using a series of if/elseif instead of a switch. It makes the code harder to read and "less standard" if you will, even though it's also "correct" and works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

It's an infinite loop, equivalent to more readable `while(true)`.

Such a loop is not used often, it typically represents operations that should continue running as long as the application runs. E.g:

- server thread accepting connections
- cleanup process sleeping for some time
- reading infinite input with pauses

The only way to escape such a loop is:

- `break`
- throwing an exception
- interrupting a thread (equivalent to throwing an `InterruptedException` inside a loop)

Answer (score 1):

This is an infinite loop. The idea is that a break condition is inside the loop

```
int i=0;
for(;;)
{
    i++;
    if (i>10) break;
}
```