# Java for(;;) loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I've been tearing into the `Netty` networking library trying to learn how to write some basic NIO networking code when I ran into something that didn't look right to me, a for-loop without anything inside of it, here's the code:

```
for (;;) {
    SocketChannel acceptedSocket = channel.socket.accept();
    if (acceptedSocket == null) {
        break;
    }
    registerAcceptedChannel(channel, acceptedSocket, thread);
}
```

I immediately checked the documentation tutorials of loops, located [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and couldn't find anything relating to this statement.

The commentation directly above this code states the following:

```
 // accept connections in a for loop until no new connection is ready
```

But this doesn't really explain to me how it works, or why, it just says what it's doing.

If you need the entire method, here it is:

```
 @Override
protected void process(Selector selector) {
    Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
    if (selectedKeys.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    for (Iterator<SelectionKey> i = selectedKeys.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        SelectionKey k = i.next();
        i.remove();
        NioServerSocketChannel channel = (NioServerSocketChannel) k.attachment();

        try {
            // accept connections in a for loop until no new connection is ready
            for (;;) {
                SocketChannel acceptedSocket = channel.socket.accept();
                if (acceptedSocket == null) {
                    break;
                }
                registerAcceptedChannel(channel, acceptedSocket, thread);
            }
        } catch (CancelledKeyException e) {
            // Raised by accept() when the server socket was closed.
            k.cancel();
            channel.close();
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            // Thrown every second to get ClosedChannelException
            // raised.
        } catch (ClosedChannelException e) {
            // Closed as requested.
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
                logger.warn(
                        "Failed to accept a connection.", t);
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // Ignore
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an infinite loop.

Comment: Every part of the `for` loop is optional.  That could be seen as a for-ever loop, since there's no condition to check, and no increment step to run.

Comment: ... that will be exited with `break;` only

Comment: Always true for loop just like while(true){}

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  I don't think that this question is a direct duplicate.  It's most certainly *related*, but I don't think that this question is a duplicate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880870/java-for-vs-whiletrue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923128/infinite-loop-application-for and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653968/what-is-the-condition-for-this-for-loop

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: None of them.  They don't ask the same question, "What does it mean?"

Comment: @Makoto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081339/what-does-for-mean-in-java

Comment: Now *that's* better.

Answer (score 5):

`for (;;)` is an infinite loop, which is equivalent to `while (true)`. Because the for-loop has no termination statement, it will never terminate.

All three components in a for-loop are optional: `for (initialization; termination; increment)`

Comment: Ah! This makes sense! I had no idea you were able to void out statements like this, so basically `for(int i =0; ;i++)` would increment i forever, correct?

Comment: @Christian.tucker Exactly.

Comment: Very handy, I'll mark this as correct when the timer expires.

Comment: I believe `for(;;)` is even more efficient than `while(true)` because it doesn't have to check anything

Comment: @user3189142 It compiles to identical bytecode, so they have same performance.